# Using sqoop to create an orc table

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have a DB2 database running with a table t1, and a hadoop cluster. I want to create an orc table in hadoop, with the same table definition as t1.
For this task I want to use Sqoop.

I tried using the sqoop create-hive-table command, but this command isn't compatible with hcatalog - and from what I've found, hcatalog is the only command, that allows me to create orc tables. 
Instead i do this:

```
sqoop import \
--driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \
--connect jdbc:db2://XXXXXXX \
--username user \
--password-file file:///pass.txt \
--query "select * from D1.t1 where \$CONDITIONS and reptime < '1864-11-16 13:23:54.749'  fetch first 1 rows only" \
--split-by 1 \
--hcatalog-database default \
--hcatalog-table t1 \
--create-hcatalog-table \
--hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile"
```

Which queries the database about somthing that does not exist and creates an orc table. Of course, this isn't optimal - any ideas on how to do this with sqoop create-hive-table, or at least without having to do a useless database query returning nothing?

Comment: Did you consider switching to Spark? Recent versions can run `CREATE` commands against the Hive Metastore, collect data from a JDBC source (in parallel if necessary), and persist that data in Hive (with native support for ORC - but you can fall back to the standard Hive SerDe libraries if necessary). All that can be done with a few lines of Python or Scala.